# How to find algorithm order of growth classification?

Tags: algorithm, classification, analysis

I have an algorithm with 3 different test data that doubles in size each time.

Here is the run time in seconds for each test data:

#### Size , time(s):

20 , 0.001

40 , 0.016

80 , 0.047

Form this how do I get the order of growth classification?

Do I need to find the cost of the algorithm first? By evaluating each line?
Or do I plot it and make a log-log graph?

Its the A* path finding algorithm, I am starting with grid size of 20 cells, and then I am doubling the grid size each time, does the data double? Or quadruple? Since it will have 20*20 amount of cells,  20*20 = 400, 40*40 = 1600, 400 is not half of 1600, so by doubling the "grid size" am I doubling the data or quadrupling?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do I come up with this function?

Comment: Anyone has anymore suggestions?